# Tabstrip not refreshing after onclick

Tags: jquery

I had a popup window, which opens from the button inside tabstrip content and i want my tabstrip to reload once the window is closed. But it is not reloading from my below script. Why??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".k-window-action.k-link").click(function () {

            var tabStrip = $("#abc").data("kendoTabStrip"); //finding tabstrip
            var tabContent = $("#abc").data("kendoTabStrip").contentHolder(1); //selecting particular tab
            tabStrip.reload(tabContent); //reloading the tab
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: hi are you updating data dynamically?
and are you updating DOM which is removing div or button whatever it is with that dynamic data in that reload?

Comment: on my window i am just saving the info after exist from window i need that data to reflect on my tab screen, so need to reload the tab when popup is closed.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you.
can you give detail.